# Get-Process un-grouping processes in powershell

Tags: powershell, process

Command: `get-process -computername $tag1 | Group-Object -Property ProcessName | Format-Table Name, @{n='Mem (KB)';e={'{0:N0}' -f (($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum / 1KB)};a='right'} -AutoSize`

It outputs 2 columns: Name and Mem (KB). The issue is that if there are two internet explorers open (iexplore.exe) it will merge them into one listing. Is there a way to not do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Group-Object` is specifically used to group items, in your case by process name. If you don't want the results grouped, you should not use `Group-Object`:

```
get-process -computername $tag1 | 
    Format-Table Name, @{n='Mem (KB)';e={'{0:N0}' -f (($_|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum / 1KB)};a='right'} -AutoSize
```